# Can't change nav-link color in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

```
<nav id="section_navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
        <div class="mx-auto my-2 order-0 order-md-1 position-relative">
            <div id="top_logo" class="container-fluid">
                <span>VirtualQR</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 dual-collapse2 order-2 order-md-1">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#section_navbar">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#section_howdoesitwork">How does it work?</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#section_pricing">Pricings</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#section_contact">Contacts</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

I can't get the nav-link to change color. I've tried other posts solutions but couldn't get it to work anyways.
I don't know if it has something to do with my code.

Comment: What exactly have you tried?

Comment: Where is your CSS for `nav-link`?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Here's what you can do.

```css
/* Select bootstrap link */

.link{
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Standart-->
<a href="#" class="nav-link">helllooo</a>

<!-- use bootstrap color labels -->
<a href="#" class="nav-link text-dark">helllooo</a>

<!-- Use Inline Css-->
<a href="#" class="nav-link" style="color: red;">helllooo</a>

<!-- Use External Css-->
<a href="#" class="nav-link link">helllooo</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the following CSS selector, you will be able to change the color of the `nav-link` class.

```css
.nav-link {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<nav id="section_navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
  <div class="mx-auto my-2 order-0 order-md-1 position-relative">
    <div id="top_logo" class="container-fluid">
      <span>VirtualQR</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 dual-collapse2 order-2 order-md-1">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#section_navbar">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#section_howdoesitwork">How does it work?</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#section_pricing">Pricings</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#section_contact">Contacts</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add inline css after each nav-link as below:

```html
<a class="nav-link" href="#section_navbar" style="color: red;">Home</a>
```

Comment: This did work! 
I'm a bit confused on why inline css worked but not in external file :s

Comment: Because of precedence.Acoording to precedence external css first execute then internal css and then inline css. So as bootstrap use the external css by using inline css you can overwrite the css .But you can not overwrite using normal external css.If you want to overwrite using external css then you have to write !important  as follows: color: red !important;

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is this:

```
.nav-link{
  color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your external CSS file

```
.nav-link {
  color: red;
}
```

OR

Put it as internal css like below

```
<head>
    <style>
           .nav-link {
              color: red;
            }

    </style>
</head>
```

OR

put it as inline CSS like below

```
<a class="nav-link" href="#section_navbar" style="color: red;">Home</a>
```